# Problem with Shade Smooth

Tags: materials, objects, object-mode

I have a trunk in Blender. I applied 'Shade Smooth' to it, and it looks good. Now, I've divided the trunk in the middle, resulting in two objects. Both have 'Shade Smooth' applied, but now there's an edge created at the intersection due to 'Shade Smooth.' How do I get rid of this? How can I achieve a smooth transition with 'Shade Smooth'?

[image]

Trunk with 'Shade Flat' But looks not gut in Game
[image]

Comment: You haven't said **how** you divided the trunk. It would be helpful if you could share your Blend file with just the trunk in it so that we can see what you've done.  You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page and then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Comment: Are you sure the cut parts do not contain non manifold edges? Go in Edit mode and inspect the meshes.

Comment: One part has a darker orange outline and the other has a brighter outline... so there are two separate objects. Is there overlapping geometry? It looks like it because the brighter outline extends to where the darker outline is. This can cause shading issues as well, but most likely a file upload would be best to check what is going on there.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven’t tried Shade Auto Smooth give that a go. Then if your exporting for game check your face normals. If any of them are red. In edit mode highlight them, go to UV tab, normals and then flip them so they are blue.

Try to merge any unneeded vertices as well and any faces that are overlapping that don’t need to be turn into single faces. Hope any of that helps